# What's the most efficient way of coding an animated header for a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I've been trying to code an animated header with canvas where randomly images (cogwheels) are added with a mouseover event where the affected cogwheel starts to animate (turn). I'm having a hard time to do that. I really wasted much time on this and decided to get help here. Is it even ok to use canvas here because I've read that there are no "eventlisteners" for single canvas objects because the canvas frame is seen as one big object. So it might be "impossible" or not efficient to make single cogwheels animate... any good tutorials to solve this or at least some tips I should hear/read about first?

Here is my code:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/cogwheel_318-102625.png");
imageURLs.push("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/cogwheel_318-102625.png");
imageURLs.push("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/cogwheel_318-102625.png");
imageURLs.push("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/cogwheel_318-102625.png");
imageURLs.push("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/cogwheel_318-102625.png");
imageURLs.push("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/cogwheel_318-102625.png");





//the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
   var imgs=[];

   var imagesOK=0;
   loadAllImages(start);

   function loadAllImages(callback){
     for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
        imagesOK++; 
          if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
             callback();
          }
    };
      img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}

function start(){

  // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
  // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]
  for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
    var randomX=Math.min(cw-imgs[i].width,Math.random()*cw);
    var randomY=Math.min(ch-imgs[i].height,Math.random()*ch);
    ctx.drawImage(imgs[i],randomX,randomY);
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on this but it appears that you can actually attach event listeners to a canvas element.  Check out [this link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/html5_canvas_mouse_events.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a resource you'd be interesting in checking out. It's called "GSAP" which stands for "GreenSock Animation Platform." It allows for a lot of easy animations with very little code using HTML5/JS.

It also mentioned working with canvas objects. In particular there is a section in the middle of the page linked that shows a "staggerTo" effect that sounds similar to what you are trying to do. (has some boxes rotate and roll into place)

I know I have been recently learning how to use it and I am quite impressed with how easy it is and they do have some basic starter tutorials right on their page along with CodePen links. Anyway, hope this helps in some form or fashion. Good luck!

http://greensock.com/tweenmax

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. This might make my work a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty awesome. I was fooling around with Jquery and CSS animations when I came across GSAP and my jaw dropped. Gotta do a little learning but even with my limited knowledge it has been a huge help. Again, best of luck!

Comment: Just confirming that GSAP is a full-featured animation framework that can easily be used to drive animations on a canvas element. This is possible because GSAP can manipulate (animate) properties inside plain-old-javascript-object. GSAP is a great animation tool for html5 canvas!